# SAML Reply Url returning Redirect (302): How to set Cookie?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cookies, saml, asp.net-apicontroller

we are using SAML for Single Sign On. Our SAML reply url is a .NET ApiController with a specified route which validates the user and in success case returns 302 Redirect with the url of an ASP.NET page (aspx).
At the moment, this page gets the user information as a GET parameter and then proceeds the login.

It all works fine. But since using a GET parameter is unsecure (Url could be copied) I would like to pass the user information to the page as a cookie.

At the moment I simply do

```
return Redirect("https://ourApp/Login.aspx");
```

I tried the following but "cookie1" is not included in Request.Headers["Cookie"] at the page:

```
HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage();
httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add( "Cookie", "cookie1=value1" );
return new RedirectResult( new Uri( "https://ourApp/Login.aspx" ), httpRequestMessage );
```

Does anyone know how I can do it? Or if not possible, what would be another solution?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found it by myself:

```
CookieHeaderValue tokenCookie = new CookieHeaderValue(...);

HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage( HttpStatusCode.Found ); // 302
responseMsg.Headers.Location = new Uri( loginUrl );
responseMsg.Headers.AddCookies( new[] { tokenCookie } );
return ResponseMessage( responseMsg );
```